# Meaning of "by the time" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence. Specially, I am confused about the meaning of the phrase "by the time".

> **By the time** honored principle that "Ought implies can", one can be
>   obliged to do A only if one has an effective choice as to whether to
>   do A.

Comment: This is mispointed: it should read "By the time-honored principle ...", meaning "According to the principle, which has been respected for a long time, ..."

Comment: @StoneyB So isn't the hyphen necessary for such a reading??

Comment: Most people would hyphenate ***time-honoured***, but as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+time+honored+principle%2Cthe+time-honored+principle&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=) shows, the two-word form is far from unknown. (It's a bit less common in [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+time+honoured+principle%2Cthe+time-honoured+principle&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20time%20honoured%20principle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20time%20-%20honoured%20principle%3B%2Cc0).)

Comment: Except among very careful writers who as a courtesy to readers make strenuous efforts to make their texts easily parsable, the hyphen in such constructions is often omitted, especially when (as here) the collocation is a common fixed phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Your parsing of the sentence is incorrect

> **By the time** honored principle

should be

> **By the time honored** principle

You are thinking of it as something like

> **By the time**, honored principles *are accepted*...

which would have a completely different meaning.